# Is there a wifi fibre available in a village

Tags: internet-explorer, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I'm a cse student and recently due to lockdown my mobile data isn't enough. So I'm looking for a wifi fibre to fix in my house.but i couldn't find any wifi fibre available in my location .i tried jio, Airtel etc. But they are not available in my location.can anyone suggest me any wifi fibre

Answer (score 0):

use 4g dongles by airtel or any service provider or you can get the tata docomo usb powered device which will run on your laptop or pc.
Or if you need wired connection, you might have a landline simply ask the service providers for internet connection through the land line cables you will be able to access them.

Cheers